# Unknow build error with OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt

my operation system is centos 7 64bit on vitrual box 
i'm try to build  openwrt  but faild

when i run `make menuconfig`  command
this is my result

```
[openwrt@localhost openwrt]$ make menuconfig
Checking 'working-make'... ok.
Checking 'case-sensitive-fs'... failed.
Checking 'gcc'... ok.
Checking 'working-gcc'... ok.
Checking 'g++'... ok.
Checking 'working-g++'... ok.
Checking 'ncurses'... ok.
Checking 'zlib'... ok.
Checking 'libssl'... ok.
Checking 'tar'... ok.
Checking 'find'... ok.
Checking 'bash'... ok.
Checking 'patch'... ok.
Checking 'diff'... ok.
Checking 'cp'... ok.
Checking 'seq'... ok.
Checking 'awk'... ok.
Checking 'grep'... ok.
Checking 'getopt'... ok.
Checking 'stat'... ok.
Checking 'md5sum'... ok.
Checking 'unzip'... ok.
Checking 'bzip2'... ok.
Checking 'wget'... ok.
Checking 'perl'... ok.
Checking 'python'... ok.
Checking 'svn'... ok.
Checking 'git'... ok.
Checking 'file'... ok.
Checking 'openssl'... ok.
Checking 'ldconfig-stub'... ok.

Build dependency: OpenWrt can only be built on a case-sensitive filesystem

Prerequisite check failed. Use FORCE=1 to override.
make: *** [staging_dir/host/.prereq-build] Error 1
```

Comment: Are you running the virtualbox from a windows host?

Windows is using case-insensitive by default, but unix-based systems are using case-sensitive filesystem.

I think it must be a virtualbox bug, can you use some other virtualization environment?

You may try to force windows to be case-sensitive (not tried):
http://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue. I runned centos by vagrant on Mac OSX. it was ok if mv the openwrt source dir to other than /vagrant.

Comment: I was trying to build directly within OSX. I was able to bypass this constraint by creating a Case-Sensitive APFS volume and `make`-ing there.

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been year but even now you are stuck here is answer

You might be using Windows as host and NTFS as file system

so NTFS is non case sensitive FS
according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity)

> In Unix filesystems, filenames are usually case-sensitive. Old Windows filesystems (VFAT, FAT32) are not case-sensitive (there cannot be a readme.txt and a Readme.txt in the same directory) but are case-preserving, i.e. remembering the case of the letters. The original FAT12 filesystem was case-insensitive.[7] Current Windows file systems, like NTFS, are case-sensitive; that is a readme.txt and a Readme.txt can exist in the same directory.

so there is chance that you have shared your folder with virtual box.
and compiling same source.
so copy source on EXT4 partition and compile.
safest way is get fresh source directly on EXT4 partition and let me know.
I think this should solve your problem.